# How to change a text on Latex class outside of Class?

Tags: xetex, class-options

I use a Latex class for my thesis which contain the following code (XeLATEX compiler):

**thesis.Cls**

```
\ProvidesClass{thesis}  
\LoadClass{article}  
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\newif\if@bscthesis
\@bscthesisfalse
\DeclareOption{bsc}{\@bscthesistrue}
\newif\if@mscthesis
\@mscthesisfalse
\DeclareOption{msc}{\@mscthesistrue}
\ProcessOptions
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@title}{

\if@mscthesis
MSC Thesis
\else
\if@bscthesis
BSC Project
\else
Doctoral Thesis
\fi\fi}{}{}
\endinput
```

**document.tex**

```
\documentclass[msc]{Test}  
\title{A great article}  
\begin{document}  
    \maketitle  
\end{document}
```

I want to change `MSC Thesis` Name outside of this Latex class But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do similarly to the class: in the preamble do

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{MSC Thesis}{Whatever you'd like}{}{}
\makeatother
```